# What would happen if you walked between a lifesize parallel capacitor with an air gap?

Tags: capacitor

Lets say the capacitor is two 7 foot x 4 foot metal pates distance between is 3 feet and the plates are hooked up to voltage.

At what voltage would it become dangerous to walk through, if any? Assuming weren't wearing anything conductive. If it's never dangerous is that because the capacitance is so low?

Is there a difference in the electric field between the plates if the voltage is dc or ac?

Comment: This is too broad and unanswerable.  For on thing, do the math comparing the situations where you walk through the middle with your arms across your chest, vs with your hands outstretched and just short of touching each wall.  Then consider this for different values of "you"

Comment: You are mostly like a water bag, so to speak. So this would be like putting some water molecules in between. But the rest would be air. I wouldn't attempt such a thing if a potentially sadistic person had set it up. But so long as the volts per meter was safe enough, I wouldn't be worried. But in a case like that, not much would be noticed, either. Low capacitance doesn't protect you from walking between two wires with high enough voltage between them. So, no, it's not always a safe thing.

Comment: Watch a fly in a bug zapper.

Comment: You would also become a dielectric with a much higher value by entering the setup. Meaning a small capacitance value is suddenly bigger. Water has a value around 70 vs air at 1

Comment: We live in a capacitor. The electrosphere (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrosphere) is charged to about 400,000 volts with respect to the surface. Near the surface of the earth, the magnitude of the field is on average around 100 V/m.

Comment: The faster you move the hotter you get

Comment: Don't touch the terminals and you are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E field is measured by Volts/meter.  We know the reduction of C due to point, line and parallel surfaces have different exponents of distance. So let’s reduce this to a simple 1D problem with series Caps of different values.

We know the smallest series cap has the highest impedance and largest voltage drop in a string of caps.

In a simulation the body dielectric which is mostly water with a dielectric constant of 80 relative to air and a slightly conductive+insulative skin as electrodes when contact is made.

So what is the charge voltage created by inserting a large C in series with very small C air values?  This depends on the dimensions voltage and C values but can be very small induced voltage.

Yet AC is not the same as DC if the R ratios are not the same. This is analogous to RC balance of a 10:1 scope probe.

Beware of creapage resistance depends on air/surface contamination ratios and humidity will affect the risks Of voltage inducement.

### Bigger risk

By inserting a dielectric in the air gap you are reducing the breakdown voltage of the air , normally 1kV~3kV/mm.  Conductor sharpness with E-field gradients create more stress and thus lowers the breakdown voltage.  So don’t even think of standing between HV lines without a proven Faraday suit.

Comment: Keep in mind even a vacuum is a dielectric similar  to air except far less contaminants and moisture with a Dk=1 by definition.